# Puzzle: Sort an array of 0's and 1's in one parse.

Tags: c, sorting, optimization

Is it possible to arrange the array made up of only 1's and 0's in descending order within one parse without using auxiliary array?
For example: Suppose you have an array `a[]={1,0,0,0,1,0,1}`, for this the expected output will be `a[]={1,1,1,0,0,0,0}`.

I have written the below C code but it finds the solution in 2 parses. Could it be optimized?

```
void arrange(int a[],int n) {
    int i,count=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if(a[i]==1)
                    count++;
            a[i]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
            a[i]=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of optimization are you looking for?   One pass of the data?

Comment: Yes, the solution should be achieved in one parse.

Comment: Parse and pass are different things, even if they are pronounced the same (they could be homophones to some people). Your code represents one parse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try this:

```
void arrange(int a[],int n)
{
    int* p = a;
    int* q = &a[n-1];

    while (p <= q) 
    {
        while (*p == 1 && p <= q) /* Find a Zero, starting from the front */
        {
            ++p;
        }
        while (*q == 0 && p <= q) /* Find a One, starting from the back */
        {
            --q;
        }

        if (p < q) /* *p == Zero, and *q == One, and p is to the left of q. */
        {
            *p = 1; 
            *q = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This works with two pointers, one starting at the front, the other starting at the back, and they both move towards the middle until they meet.

Along the way, if the two pointers find a 0 on the left and a 1 on the right, swap the values, then continue.

*(code is untested, but the outline seems solid)*

Comment: Thanks, I compiled it. It works fine. As I am sending the size in parameter n, we need to alter the code `int* q = &a[n]` to `int* q = &a[n-1]`

Comment: Nice idea, but seems a bit too complex :)

Comment: `while (*p == 1 && p <= q)` will get out of array bounds if the array consists of `1` only. Should be `while (p <= q && *p == 1)` I think.

Comment: @Inspired, it works for all the cases. As I told in my earlier comment you must change `int* q = &a[n]` to `int* q = &a[n-1]` since `n` contains the number of elements in an array not the index of last element in an array.

Comment: @PrathviRaj But wouldn't it try to dereference p (`*p`) when p == q+1 before terminating the loop?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: WTF.  Your tests make no sense.  99 and 88 are not described as valid input.   Your test-arrays have 12 elements, but you're only passing n=7.  Not a valid test.

Comment: I like the idea; it is just that there's an implementation detail that's wrong — and it is already diagnosed in the comments.  The end point needs to be `int q = &a[n-1];`.  With that fix in place, the code behaves perfectly correctly.  I upgraded my test code splatted above to print the whole array, not just the subset, and it demonstrated zeros written over the 88 entries.

Comment: They do make sense, but not when formatted as a comment.  I'll paste my code in an answer and then delete it — you can see that.

Comment: I've posted my test code formatted in a deleted answer (10k users can see it; sorry to the rest). The array passed to `arrange()` is a subset of the 12-element arrays — the subset not including the 99 or 88 values. Those are there as markers to help spot misbehaviour by the `arrange()` function. When the code as posted in this answer is used (with `int *q = &a[n];`), the test harness shows that (a) the `arrange()` function writes out of bounds and (b) the 'all 1' case does not terminate. It also shows that with the corrected `arrange()` function (with `int *q = &a[n-1];`), the result is fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is the code in this answer fixed now, after all?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; You should have to make and attach a link of screenshot for your code (for <10k users) :(

Comment: @H2CO3: the code in this answer is now fixed; the line `int *q = &a[n-1];` is correct and the code works perfectly with it.

Comment: @haccks: It is too big to be a good screen shot, and it is a comment on an answer (albeit a big comment) which is why it is deleted as not-an-answer.  Work on getting to 10k and you can see it too. :D

Answer (score 6):

```
for (size_t i = 0, count = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] == 1) a[count++] = 1;
  if (i >= count) a[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: What if a[0] is a 1 initially?

Comment: Oops. Thanks, Jim, I'll fix this.

Comment: @Inspired I think `a[count+=a[i]] |= a[i]` will remove the need for first `if` statement.  The second `if` can be removed as well if we split the loop into two, the first loop going over 1's till a 0 is encountered, the second loop taking over from there on.

Comment: @unxnut Then the code would be branchless, great. It also seems to me that the initial value of `count` should be -1 then, because a[count+=a[i]] increases `count` too early.

Comment: I like this one. It was very non-obvious to me that it's correct :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about recursion? Simple and elegant, as always.

```
void countAndRewrite(int arr[], size_t n, size_t *cone, size_t total)
{
    if (n) {
        if (arr[0])
            ++*cone;

        countAndRewrite(arr + 1, n - 1, cone, total);
        arr[0] = total - n < *cone;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
    size_t cone = 0;
    countAndRewrite(arr, 7, &cone, 7);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    printf("arr[%zu] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its little complicated to understand, I usually avoid recursive solutions. Anyways thanks for the help :)

Comment: Elegant, yes, but simple? :) Nice solution.

Comment: @Inspired Thanks! Again, that depends on your taste :) I find it quite intuitive. Maybe I'm just too occupied with implementing my virtual machine and I always think in terms of stacks :P

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, for a binary tree: `queue.push(root); while (!queue.empty()) { node = queue.front(); queue.pop(); if (node!=NULL) { process_node(node); queue.push(node->left); queue.push(node->right);  } }` :)

Comment: @Inspired Yup, that's it!

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try!

(read comments):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int a[]={1,0,0,0,1,0,1};
    int n = 7,
        i,
        index = 0;

   while(index < n && a[index]) index++; // skip initial 1's
   for(i = index; i < n; i++){  
     if(a[i]) a[index++] = 1; // if `1` at a[i] make its 0 and
     a[i] = 0;                // make at index 1. 
   }

   for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%3d", a[i]);
   }
    return 1;
}
```

Check working code @ideone's links:

**Case-1:**  [`{1,0,0,0,1,0,1}`](http://ideone.com/EHfg73)
**Case-2:**  [`{1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1, 1}`](http://ideone.com/hoQv5W)
**Case-3:**  [`{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`](http://ideone.com/JLSBxn)
**Case-4:**  [`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`](http://ideone.com/rWV70J)
**Case-5:**  [`{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}`](http://ideone.com/6c5dLw)

So I think it works correct!
its simple, it need only `n` iterations.
complexity wise `O(n)`.

Comment: I think it will fail for `1,0,0,1,1,0,1`  let me check

Comment: This will fail for `1,1,1,...,1` (out of array bounds in the `while` loop).

Comment: All solutions (even 2-pass) have `O(n)` time complexity since O(n) = O(2*n).

Comment: @Inspired  yes it take only `n` iterations only not even 2n ..a bit better... NO?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Better, yes, but it's still O(n) or O(2*n) or O(1000*n). I'm just stressing the meaning of big-O.

Answer (score 0):

Just an other way of it  .

Have two pivots one from beginning and other at end like the bellow one ,

```
for(int i=0, j=n-1;i<j;)
{
if(a[i]==1 && a[j]==0) swap(a[i],a[j]);
else if(a[i]==1 && a[j]==1) j--;
else if(a[i]==0 && a[j]==0) i++;
else if(a[i]==0 && a[j]==1) {j--; i++;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
    int N = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int p = 0, q = 1;

while (q != N) {
    if (arr[p] > arr[q]) {
        arr[p] = 0;
        arr[q] = 1;
        p++;
        q++;
    }
    else {
        q++;
        if (arr[p] == 0)
            p++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    cout << arr[i];

return 0;
```