# Time complexity for sorting an array of binary numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

Given the following array: `| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |`

we have to sort the above array like all 1's on the right side and 0's on left.

i have come up with 2 algorithms in C++.

1st one:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(a[i] == 1 && i != n - 1) {
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(a[j] == 0) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2nd one:

```
int x = 0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(a[i] == 1) {
        for(j = n-x-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if(a[j] == 0) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                x++;
                break;
            }
        }
    if(x > n / 2)
    break;
}
```

can you tell me the time complexity of both. and which one performs better
also suggest me a better algorithm with explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Read [Puzzle: Sort an array of 0's and 1's in one parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900922/puzzle-sort-an-array-of-0s-and-1s-in-one-parse/17901084#17901084)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just count the number of ones then refill your array with zeroes first `lengthOfArray - sum` elements and then with ones. Complexity will be O(n).

In your both cases you have a complexity of O(n²)

Comment: This can also be thought of as a Radix Sort.

Comment: @Adam or bucket sort. Still, I don't consider this question should be solved using a sort algorithm when there is something more straight forward.

Comment: It's more similar to [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Answer (score 3):

As @Alexandru said that is good gives O(N) , you just need to iterate twice

1. To find count of 0, 1
2. To fill the array with 1, 0 as count says .

If you are looking for another alternative sort , You can look this which is O(N) .

```
for(int i=0, j=n-1;i<j;)
{
if(a[i]==1 && a[j]==0) swap(a[i],a[j]);
else if(a[i]==1 && a[j]==1) j--;
else if(a[i]==0 && a[j]==0) i++;
else if(a[i]==0 && a[j]==1) {j--; i++;}
}
```

Comment: + correct! you can simplified as [Puzzle: Sort an array of 0's and 1's in one parse.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900922/puzzle-sort-an-array-of-0s-and-1s-in-one-parse/17901084#17901084)

Answer (score 2):

1st one will sort the array in O(n^2) time as it is direct implication of bubble sort. but 2nd method will not sort the array because you are swapping the 1 with the first 0 while transversing from end. So if your array is like `0 0 0 1 1 1` then 2nd code will swap the 1 in 3rd index with 0 of 2nd index and at last it looks like `0 0 1 1 1 0`. And i don't know what that x is ?